# Finding distance between positions of same point on two different layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance

I am trying to calculate the difference between the positions of the same point on two different layers. One layer is a shapefile, other layer is a text file, and each point has a unique identifier, Stationval.
Found something similar, using a virtual layer, however my python skills are not good enough to convert this.
Was also looking for the Points2One plugin, with no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With all due respect, your question has me confused.  If they are "...the ***same*** point..." wouldn't the distance thus be zero?  I mean, they are the same point, after all.

But, in spite of my confusion, perhaps I can point you to two QGIS tools that may be of help:

1. NNJOIN Plugin:  Determines the distance From each feature to its nearest single feature
2. Vector > Analysis Tools > Distance Matrix tool: This returns the distance from each feature to every other feature (pairwise comparison).

Comment: Thank you Stu Smith, nnjoin did the trick. Sorry for not being clear enough: one layer has the points as planned, other layer points on field.

Comment: Great, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the field calculator with a expression like that:

```
distance(geometry(get_feature('LayerA','ID_ColumnA','ID_A')),geometry(get_feature('LayerB','ID_ColumnB','ID_B')))
```

Comment: Thank you eurojam, I shall try your suggestion to see what solution is the most suitable for me.